# shell script returning file not found

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a simple shell script that reads a file and finds another file name whithin the file read and performs some basic operations (cp and mv) on both files, simplified code below (but results are the same):

```
#!/bin/bash


for header in `ls -l XXXXACT_*.dat | awk '{ print $9 }'`
do
    payload=`cat $header | nawk -F "/" '{ print $8 }' | sed 's/APP.*//' | tr -d "\012"`
    echo  "$header"
    echo "$payload"
    ls -l $payload
```

The result that I get is the following:

```
XXXXFACT_000000424.dat
FILEACT_000424.TXT
FILEACT_000424.TXT: No such file or directory
```

but if I run ls on the file name I get a result:

```
ls -l FILEACT_000424.TXT
-rwxr-xr-x   1 stlts    stlts        292 Feb  9 12:14 FILEACT_000424.TXT
```

Find below an example of file XXXXFACT_000000424.dat:

```
0000 APP_APPLI_CODE XXXFACTAPP_FILE_NB 000424APP_FLOW IMPORT
0101 APP_MSG_NB 001APP_COMPANY XXXXXXXX_TESTAPP_SERVICE   XXXXXS0_IMPORTAPP_MSG_NAT FICAPP_MSG_TYPE FICAPP_CORR_ID XXXXXX20XXXAPP_MSG_TXT_TYPE FICAPP_MSG_TXT /xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/fileact/xxxxxx/import/FILEACT_000424.TXTAPP_ENDFCT EOM
0000 APP_ENDFILE EOF
```

Any explanation to why I am getting this behaviour, and/or ideas/suggestions on how to address this are welcome.

The script is to run on SunOs 5.10, I get the following result with cp:

```
cp: cannot access FILEACT_000424.TXT
```

And I have made sure that I am in the correct directory.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Thank you @shellter I have checked the folder I am in several times, the results are the same even if I specify the full directory structure

Comment: Your `tr -d "\012"` tells me that you may be dealing with funny line endings.  Are you running this in Windows, or do your filenames perhaps have Ctrl-M's at their ends?

Comment: the files come from Windows after being modified by an inhouse app, I get one extra line before and after the file name:        cat XXXXFACT_000000424.dat | nawk -F "/" '{ print $8 }' | sed 's/APP.*//'

FILEACT_000424.TXT

But the script is run on a Solaris server

Comment: Thanks @shellter I have tried that before, same results...

Answer (score 2):

For the files you're copying over from Windows, convert them with [`dos2unix`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5165/dos2unix-1.html)

Rewriting your code snippet:

```
for header in XXXXACT_*.dat; do
    payload=$( nawk '/\/.*APP/ {sub(/.*\//,""); sub(/APP.*/,""); print}' "$header" )
    echo "$header"
    echo "$payload"
    ls -l "$payload"
```

Notes

- Don't loop over `ls` output, loop over the filename expansion directly
- Don't need `cat` when a program can handle files themselves
- `awk` can do what you're using `sed` for
- use `$()` instead of backticks
- always quote `"$variables"`, except when you know exactly when to not use them.

Comment: beautiful and clean piece of code, learned some new ways of doing things with it, thanks! Unfortunately the results are the same, I have converted the files with dos2unix

Comment: Change your script to `printf "%s" "$header" | od -c` -- is there a trailing carriage return? Are you certain these files are all in the current directory?

Comment: Hi glenn jackman, there was a non printable `^W` after the file name which I didn't expect, I caught it by chance when running a `cat -v $header`, this issue has now been resolved, answer below. Thank you for all your input!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that read and suggested new approaches to resolve my problem, this was my first post here and I learned plenty already!

I figured it out, I ran a cat –v on the $header file and could see that after the $payload file name which is not visible:

```
FILEACT_000093.TXT^W
```

I have tried to remove it with sed as a test, sample code below:

```
for header in XXXXFACT_*.dat; do

    payload=$( nawk '/\/.*APP/ {sub(/.*\//,""); sub(/APP.*/,""); print}' "$header" )
    echo $header
    payloadx=$( echo "${payload}" | sed 's/^W//g' )
    echo "$payloadx"
    ls -l "$payloadx"
    echo ""

done
```

The above works as expected

Comment: Is the .DAT file using ^W as a record separator? That may make the nawk call a little cleaner. Otherwise, build this into nawk: `sub(/^WAPP.*/, "")` where "^W" is a literal Ctrl-W of course.

Comment: PERFECT! adding `sub(/^WAPP.*/, "")` works as you suggested, thanks once again. Any advice on awk reading materials(and shell scripting in general)?

Comment: StackOverflow has really been the best place for me to learn.